# How to change Websphere 9 log files' permissions

Tags: logging, permissions, installation, websphere

In a WebSphere 9 installation on Linux, I am trying to change the default file permissions of the generated log files to be more permissive. The default permissions of the log files are these:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 was root SystemOut.log
```

(I am referring to the JVM logs)

I want to allow all users to also write the log files. In development, I find it useful to delete log content so that I can start fresh when analyzing exceptions.

My research only returned that some parameter exists, that is only described for Liberty (WLP_SKIP_UMASK) without any details on usage, effect, etc.

What can I set up in WebSphere so that the JVM log files have permission `-rw-rw-rw-`  ?

To be even more specific about my setup and why I need this: my WAS is set up in a docker container; the log directory in WAS is linked to a location on my disk. It would be a hassle to manually change permission every time, as the log files get rotated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the umask for the JVMs as 000. Setting umask to 000 will give the folder permissions as 777 (if it doesn't exist already) and file permissions as 666 (-rw-rw-rw-) to the newly created files.

Here are some references of umasks value and chmod values :

How to change the umask for a JVM:

1. Take the backup of the profile using backupConfig.sh from Profile bin directory. (This step is a life-saver in all cases)
2. Stop the JVM you need to change the umask for.
3. Login to WAS Console
4. Go to Servers --> Server Types --> WebSphere Application Servers
5. Select the JVM you wish to change the umask for
6. Expand Java and Process Management on the right
7. Click Process Execution
8. Change the value of UMASK to 000
9. Rename the existing log file. This is needed if the logs are not rolled after every restart. If the file is not renamed, then the new permissions will not be in effect till the new file is generated.
10. Start the JVM

Just for the reference, please find the chart below for umask and corresponding chmod values

```
 **Umask   |  Created Files     |   Created Directories**
------------------------------------------------------------  
 1. 000        666 (rw-rw-rw-)       777   (rwxrwxrwx)
 2. 002        664 (rw-rw-r--)       775   (rwxrwxr-x)
 3. 022        644 (rw-r--r--)       755   (rwxr-xr-x)
 4. 027        640 (rw-r-----)       750   (rwxr-x---)
 5. 077        600 (rw-------)       700   (rwx------)
 6. 277        400 (r--------)       500   (r-x------)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. No, I had not succeeded so far, or I would have posted the answer myself. I assumed it was not possible so I looked for a better log-surfer for linux and I'm moderately content with klogg.